# Material-ui GridTile Title Color

Tags: fonts, colors, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have looked all over, and if its here just yell at me! I am trying to change the title color in a material-ui GridTile title. I have tried adding a style={{color: black;}} that does nothing. I want Choose Me to be another color. Any ideas? I really appreciate any direction I should look in!

Here is the code I am looking at:

```
  <GridTile
      key={inspiration.image_url}
      style={{font: 'webdings'}}
      title="Choose Me"
      actionIcon={<IconButton><LocalFlorist color="lightgreen"/></IconButton>}
      actionPosition="right"
      titlePosition="bottom"
      titleBackground="linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)"
      cols={ 1 }
      rows={ 1 }
      onClick={() => {
        console.log('++++ containers/inspirations.js this.props.selectInspiration(this.props.inspiration) value => ', this.props.selectInspiration(inspiration));
        this.props.push('/spacecreator');
      } }
    >
      <image style={
        {
          width: '100%'
        }
      }
      src={ inspiration.image_url } />
    </GridTile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [GitHub source for Grid-Tile](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/grid-list/grid-tile.jsx), the text color is a theme dependent value -

```
titleWrap: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginLeft: actionPos !== 'left' ? gutterLess : 0,
    marginRight: actionPos === 'left' ? gutterLess : 0,
    color: themeVariables.textColor,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
```

Follow the [instructions on this page](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes) to override the theme variable for your component.

Comment: I forgot to thank you! You saved my deadline.

note to self: rtfm!